# What built in python function would I use to split up a string into each separate character?

Tags: python

If I had a 4 digit code saved in a variable as a string without spaces between the digits, how could I split them up into the separate digits?

Comment: `code_digits = [int(digit) for digit in code_str]`

Comment: Characters within a string are addressable as an immutable array, so they are kinda split up already.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass any iterable to a list, including a string.

```
>>> list("1234")
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

If you want to iterate over the digits, you don't have to to convert it to a list, you can iterate over the string.

```
for digit in "1234":
    print(digit)
```